# connecting records in 3 tables randomly

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I have three tables:

```
categories (id)
product_models(id, category_id)
products(id, product_id, category_id)
```

There are records on each table (lorem ipsum content), i want to connect the data.
I've changed already the product_models, executing this query:

```
    update product_models
    set category_id = (select id from categories order by RAND() limit 1)
```

How can I use **a single query** that will map all the products to a product model and update the category also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add constraints and references to the tables as appropriate so that when you update one table, the others will be updated as well.

Comment: I understand and will get to it, tho in this application items can be orphans.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your third table structure is (id, product_model_id, category_id), another assumption is that you have a composite foreign key (product_model_id, category_id), then you have to update the third table like below

```
UPDATE products P
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, category_id from product_models ) M
ON P.product_id = M.id
SET P.category_id = M.category_id
```

Comment: seems like this query will update only one connection, between the products to the category. tho it's sort of an answer, i look for a single query that will connect ALL 3 tables